# redirect uri error while uploading file to google drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, tornado, google-oauth

I am trying to upload file to my google drive via my web application.
 I am creating client id for  my web application as follows:

```
Client ID:  916885716524-1qvrrridktedn50pasooe1ndepe1oefp.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email address: 916885716524-1qvrrridktedn50pasooe1ndepe1oefp@developer.gserviceaccount.com
Client secret:  6an3xatjgt7sU4Y5v61er7hd
Redirect URIs:  http://localhost:9000/
JavaScript origins: http://localhost:9000/
```

I am downloading the json file and saving it.

Now, whenever user is trying to upload from web app.

It is going to the authentication window. Now when I am selecting the account, It is saying that :

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request: http:// localhost:8080/ did not match a registered redirect URI

Request Details

```
from_login=1
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file
response_type=code
access_type=offline
redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/
as=36ff9556bb7c2164
display=page
pli=1
client_id=916885716524-1qvrrridktedn50pasooe1ndepe1oefp.apps.googleusercontent.com
authuser=0
hl=en
```

As You can see I have not mentioned 8080 in my redirect uri but then also it is trying to redirect to that uri.

My code is as follows:

In my handler:

```
Class Upload(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # some logic here by which I am getting the file path
        # then calling following function from another file
        file_path = "/home/user/filename.txt"
        upload_to_drive(file_path)
        self.finish(json.dumps({"status": "success"}))
```

The other file where I am writing logic for upload to google drive is:

# a help full link is https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-
    python#step_1_enable_the_drive_api

```
import os
import sys
import socket
import logging
import httplib2
from mimetypes import guess_type

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.file import Storage
import apiclient
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.tools import run

# Log only oauth2client errors
logging.basicConfig(level="ERROR")


token_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'sample.dat')

CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'client_secrets.json')

# Helpful message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS file is missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to download the client_secrets.json file
and save it at:

   %s

""" % os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), CLIENT_SECRETS)

FLOW = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS,
    scope=[
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
    ],
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)


def authorize(token_file, storage):
    if storage is None:
        storage = Storage(token_file)
    credentials = storage.get()

 if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

# Create an httplib2.Http object and authorize it with credentials
http = httplib2.Http()

credentials.refresh(http)
http = credentials.authorize(http)
return http


def upload_file(file_path, file_name, mime_type):
# Create Google Drive service instance
    http = httplib2.Http()
    drive_service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http)

    media_body = MediaFileUpload(file_path,
                             mimetype=mime_type,
                             resumable=False)
    body = {
      'title': file_name,
      'description': 'backup',
      'mimeType': mime_type,
    }
    permissions = {
      'role': 'reader',
      'type': 'anyone',
      'value': None,
      'withLink': True
    }

    # Insert a file
    # drive_services.files() is at first an empty list.
    file = drive_service.files().insert(body=body, media_body=media_body).execute()
    # Insert new permissions and create file instance
    drive_service.permissions().insert(fileId=file['id'], body=permissions).execute()
    print 'file uploaded !!'


def file_properties(file_path):
    mime_type = guess_type(file_path)[0]
    file_name = file_path.split('/')[-1]
    return file_name, mime_type

def upload_to_drive(file_path):
    try:
        with open(file_path) as f: pass
    except IOError as e:
        print(e)
        sys.exit(1)

    http = authorize(token_file, None)
    file_name, mime_type = file_properties(file_path)

    upload_file(file_path, file_name, mime_type)
```

I am not able to understand where I am doing wrong. Please somebody explain a way out of this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the last of the the `Upload` class you have

```
self.redirect("/")
```

If you're running this on a local development server, it expects there to be something at http:// localhost:8080/, the default host/address for your development server.

Comment: redirection to localhost:8080 is coming after oauth. Here I wrote self.redirect("/") just to ensure that call is finished. Consider it as if I am doing a dump there. I will modify the post, which will make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not intimate with the python library, but whichever call is constructing the Authentication URI, it's apparently putting a `http://localhost:8080` in the parameters, as you can see in your post.  So either you need to figure out how to change the behavior of the python library to put in `localhost:9000`, or you need to change the registration in the developer console to allow `localhost:8080`.

I find that as I work my way through developing, staging, and product-izing an app, I end up with a half-dozen different redirects building up in the dev console. No apparent harm to it that I can see.

Answer (score 0):

We need to modify oauth2client.tool a bit

You can specify your ports like following and then every thing will work fine.

```
gflags.DEFINE_multi_int('auth_host_port', [8080, 8090, 9000],.....
)
```